# How to dynamically generate chart from google chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to implement chart from the following link
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart.html

Below is piece of code taken from phtml file,

$sale has the array like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 19.92
    [1] => 159.15
    [2] => 374.96
    [3] => 319.5
    [4] => 237
)
```

$month has the array like,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 11
)
```

Below script will generate chart based on array value

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sale_arr = <?php echo json_encode($sale); ?>;
        var month_arr = <?php echo json_encode($months); ?>;
        alert(month_arr)
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        //data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        var result = '';
         for(var i=0; i<month_arr.length; i++) {
          result += '["'+month_arr[i]+'",' +sale_arr[i]+'],';
         }     
        alert(result);  
        data.addRows([
          result
        ]);

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, title: 'Order',
                          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}}
                         });
      }
    </script>
```

I need to form the values like

```
data.addRows([
  ['4', 1000,
  ['5', 1170],
  ['6', 660],
  ['7', 1030]
]);
```

in my script `result` will generate `["7",19.92],["8",159.15],["9",374.96],["10",319.5],["11",237],` .Also i added the result as

```
    data.addRows([
      result
    ]);
```

This will make some error on script. What i done wrong this code. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: I am getting same problem, did you find any solution please let me know how you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Your var result is giving you an extra comma telling the code there is another value when there really isn't

```
var result = '';
for(var i=0; i<month_arr.length; i++) {
    result += '["'+month_arr[i]+'",' +sale_arr[i]+'],';
}     
result = result.substring(0, result.length - 1)
alert(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, i need to pass that result inside data.addRows. If i do like that i said in my question , throws error. Any idea on this ?

Comment: result is currently a string, maybe you should make result an object before you pass it through data.addRows?

Comment: i found on documentation,
    * numOrArray - Either a number or an array:
          o Number - A number specifying how many new, unpopulated rows to add.
          o Array - An array of row objects used to populate a set of new rows. Each row is an object as described in addRow(). Use null or an empty array entry for an empty cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think given parameter to AddRows function should be an array, not string.

Also you should remove last comma in order to have a string that can be interpreted to an array.

```
data.addRows(
      eval('[' + result.substring(0, result.length - 1) + ']')
    )
```

But using `eval` is not the best way to do it. While you are creating your `result` data, you can create an array instead of string. Here the code:

```
var result = [];

for(var i=0; i<month_arr.length; i++) {
    result.push( [month_arr[i], sale_arr[i]] );
}    

data.addRows(result);
```